# Terraform Kubernetes Provider - cannot load Kubernetes client config

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

In my terraform project, I have my own module which creates an AKS cluster with RBAC enabled. This module has an output **aks_public_fqdn** which holds the FQDN of the cluster.

```
module "aks" {
  source = "./aks"

  environment        = local.environment
  region             = local.region
  instance_id        = local.workload_id
  application        = local.workload_name
  resource_group     = local.rg_name
  kubernetes_version = local.kubernetes_version

}
```

Once the cluster is up and running, I would like to create some K8S resources through Terraform with the Kubernetes provider.

To authenticate I am using the following code snippet:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.aks.aks_public_fqdn}"
  insecure = true

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "kubelogin"
    args = [
      "get-token",
      "--environment",
      "AzurePublicCloud",
      "--server-id",
      "3333333-3333333-3333333",
      "--login",
      "azurecli"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try to run terraform apply I get:

```
Error: Provider configuration: cannot load Kubernetes client config
invalid configuration: default cluster has no server defined
```

The only entry I have in my kubeconfig file is the context for my local kind cluster. What is missing here?

Am I hit by the following github issue?
[Provider Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2430)

Comment: I am not sure about terraform , but in Azure CLI the first step is `az aks get-credentials` which brings the server context to the local config file.

Comment: Would this work `kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli`?

Comment: @YK1 Hello Guys, I think it has nothing to do with azurecli. I think the problem is around terraform. The providers should be known in planning time, however I am referenceing the output one of my modules, and that is only known after apply.

Comment: This appears as if something in your local execution environment is overriding the parameter values in the `provider` block with a preference for your kubeconfig.

Comment: @MattSchuchard running  env | grep -i "kube" gives back nothing, so I doubt it. I have modified my original post, and included a possible github issue. Am I hit by that?

Comment: Not according to the question's current content. That issue is related to the simultaneous initial management of a cluster's infrastructure and the cluster itself.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am doing the same thing. First, creating an AKS cluster in Azure and would like to use that cluster as my context.

Comment: @MattSchuchard included the cluster creation part into the question

Comment: You would need to downgrade to 2.3.2 at the latest of the Kubernetes provider (API v1), or `-target` the module first.

Comment: @MattSchuchard You are right, it is working. How did you find this? If you could elaborate on this, I would be very grateful for that. Additionally, if you could do this in an answer I would be more than happy to accept that as the final solution. Good job, no ideas how you managed to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kubernetes` provider configuration contains an output from the module declared as `aks`. Prior to version `2.4.0` of the Kubernetes provider it was possible to simultaneously manage a Kubernetes cluster backing infrastructure and the cluster itself at initial provisioning (or subsequent Delete/Create) by configuring the provider with either resource attributes, or with `data` attributes. At version `2.4.0` of the Kubernetes provider, the new experimental Kubernetes provider with the latest Terraform SDK and Kubernetes Go SDK bindings (and consequently Kubernetes API) stabilized and replaced the former Kubernetes provider (ergo why some resources are marked `v1` and `v2` as the provider still contained some of the legacy code for backwards support, and only the minor version of the provider was iterated and not the major version according to semantic versioning rules). With this new provider and its use of the modern Kubernetes API it became no longer possible for this simultaneous management at initial provisioning. Therefore the error in the question is observed as Terraform's Kubernetes provider is attempting to configure with a non-existent cluster instead of charting a dependency hierarchy that would imply the provider is dependent upon the `aks` module.

With all this in mind it becomes clear there are two workarounds. The first is to downgrade the Kubernetes provider to the last version of the old provider:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.3.2"
    }
  }
}
```

The other solution would be to [`-target`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#resource-targeting) the `aks` module first to manually enforce the dependency and populate the outputs, and then subsequently manage the entire Terraform config:

```
terraform plan -target=module.aks
```